# Aframe textures are not applied and the scene is fully lit

Tags: textures, aframe, box

I have assigned textures to two cubes but only the black surface is visible. The scene is sufficiently lit, the textures are loaded as assets. I am using codesandbox.io as IDE, I have tested it locally and it repeats the same behavior. To discard a cube it has the texture and the normal one and in an entity I have assigned only the texture.

Thanks in advance

my code is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <img id="boxTexture" src="textures/woodfloor.jpg" />
        <img id="boxTextureNormal" src="textures/woodfloor_normal.jpg" />
      </a-assets>

      <a-light type="ambient" color="blue"></a-light>
      <a-box
        color="red"
        position="0 3 -3"
        src="#boxTexture"
        normal="#boxTextureNormal"
      ></a-box>
      <a-entity
        geometry="primitive: box;"
        position="0 1 -5"
        material="src: #boxTexture; repeat: 100 20"
      >
      </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

One screenshot is attached:

[image: screenshot codesandbox]

Comment: do you have any errors in browser?

Comment: Probably files not served via local server? Browser cannot access the local file system because of security policies. https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load For more specific answers I recommend sharing code with https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: In the end I have used glitch. There is one cube that looks the normal texture but not the final texture and the other cube is still dark. The glitch code is as follows:
Code:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/grafeno30-aframe-textures

Live site:
https://grafeno30-aframe-textures.glitch.me

Comment: In the end I have used glitch. There is one cube that looks the normal texture but not the final texture and the other cube is still dark. The glitch code is as follows:
Code:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/grafeno30-aframe-textures

Live site:
https://grafeno30-aframe-textures.glitch.me

Comment: Hasn't it happened to someone that the textures are not applied?